# Magento 1.9 - Add to cart not working for some products

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

The Magento store of my customer is running under version 1.9.1.1.

It appears than some products can't be added to cart, with the simple returning message "Unable to add product to cart". Older products may be added, as opposed to more recently added products.

I have this error in exception.log :

```
Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`htf_magento`.`sales_flat_quote_item`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SALES_FLAT_QUOTE_ITEM_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity_OLD` (`entity_id`) ON DEL), query was: INSERT INTO `sales_flat_quote_item` (`quote_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `product_id`, `store_id`, `is_virtual`, `sku`, `name`, `applied_rule_ids`, `free_shipping`, `is_qty_decimal`, `weight`, `qty`, `price`, `base_price`, `discount_percent`, `discount_amount`, `base_discount_amount`, `tax_percent`, `tax_amount`, `base_tax_amount`, `row_total`, `base_row_total`, `row_weight`, `product_type`, `base_cost`, `price_incl_tax`, `base_price_incl_tax`, `row_total_incl_tax`, `base_row_total_incl_tax`, `hidden_tax_amount`, `base_hidden_tax_amount`, `weee_tax_disposition`, `weee_tax_row_disposition`, `base_weee_tax_disposition`, `base_weee_tax_row_disposition`, `weee_tax_applied`, `weee_tax_applied_amount`, `weee_tax_applied_row_amount`, `base_weee_tax_applied_amount`) VALUES (?, '2018-07-23 13:09:08', '2018-07-23 13:09:08', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' in /home/htf/www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /home/htf/www/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/htf/www/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/htf/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/htf/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#4 /home/htf/www/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#5 /home/htf/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#6 /home/htf/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('sales_flat_quot...', Array)
#7 /home/htf/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item))
#8 /home/htf/www/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php(749): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#9 /home/htf/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(652): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item->save()
#10 /home/htf/www/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(340): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->save()
#11 /home/htf/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->_afterSave()
#12 /home/htf/www/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(1966): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#13 /home/htf/www/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php(459): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->save()
#14 /home/htf/www/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(223): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->save()
#15 /home/htf/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->addAction()
#16 /home/htf/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('add')
#17 /home/htf/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#18 /home/htf/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#19 /home/htf/www/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#20 /home/htf/www/index.php(105): Mage::run('', 'store')
#21 {main}
```

Would anyone have any idea of the origin of the problem?

Comment: Is it a Magento default or custom module?

Comment: I get this Magento which has been managed by other agencies before, and there may have been customizations of modules. ManaDEV filter and SEO management modules have also been installed. I tried to disable these and re-index, but the same error still appears.

Comment: I guess a foreign key is being linked to the catalog_product_entity_OLD table while it should be connected to the catalog_product_entity table from the sales_flat_quote_item table.